# Java annotation value from property file

Tags: java, spring

Do you know if it is possible to pass property from file into annotation, when using Spring?

e.g app.properties

```
p='dev'
```

and in java

```
@Profile(${p})
```

Is such thing possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not possible. Annonations are compile time only so you cannot replace the value in runtime.